# Why GetType returns System.Int32 instead of Nullable<Int32>?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, nullable, gettype

Why is the output of this snippet `System.Int32` instead of `Nullable<Int32>`?

```
int? x = 5;
Console.WriteLine(x.GetType());
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`GetType()` is a method of `object`.
To call it, the `Nullable<T>` struct must be boxed.

You can see this in the IL code:

```
//int? x = 5;
IL_0000:  ldloca.s    00 
IL_0002:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0003:  call        System.Nullable<System.Int32>..ctor

//Console.WriteLine(x.GetType());
IL_0008:  ldloc.0     
IL_0009:  box         System.Nullable<System.Int32>
IL_000E:  callvirt    System.Object.GetType
IL_0013:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

Nullable types are treated specially by CLR; it is impossible to have a boxed instance of a nullable type.
Instead, boxing a nullable type will result in a null reference (if `HasValue` is false), or the boxed value (if there is a value).

Therefore, the `box System.Nullable<System.Int32>` instruction results in a boxed `Int32`, not a boxed `Nullable<Int32>`.

Therefore, it is impossible for `GetType()` to *ever* return `Nullable<T>`.

To see this more clearly, look at the following code:

```
static void Main()
{
    int? x = 5;
    PrintType(x);   
}
static void PrintType<T>(T val) {
    Console.WriteLine("Compile-time type: " + typeof(T));
    Console.WriteLine("Run-time type: " + val.GetType());
}
```

This prints

> Compile-time type: System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]
>   Run-time type: System.Int32

Answer (score 9):

`GetType()` isn't virtual, and is thus defined only on `object`. As such, to make the call, the `Nullable<Int32>` must first be boxed. Nullables have special boxing rules, though, so only the `Int32` value is boxed, and that's the type reported.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why Nullable<T> (and other structures, for that matter) shouldn't have defined their own GetType methods which would shadow those of Object?  It seems incredibly goofy that if Foo is a value type, Foo.GetType() should require the creation of a new heap object to store the boxed content of Foo, when in fact that content is going to be ignored.  Wouldn't it be more efficient to just have Foo.GetType() shadowed with a method that simply returned the appropriate Type object?

Comment: @supercat I'm not sure I'm qualified to answer that question. One thing I will say is that nullable structs are goofy in a bunch of ways, owing to the fact that they were basically tacked on after-the-fact, rather than incorporated into the language from the start. The general point still holds, I suppose, since you need to box an `int` variable to call `GetType()` on that as well. Since the types where this would matter are always going to be loaded, it's possible that this is a space/documentation consistency concession. Perhaps Eric Lippert can shed some more light.

Comment: @supercat `GetType()` doesn't really make sense for a `sealed` type, because you can just use `typeof()`. `Nullable<T>`, like all `struct`s, is implicitly sealed. If it doesn't really make sense to call `GetType()`, sure, it'll be made to work if there's no reason not to, but that's all, don't expect too much effort in optimization.

Comment: @hvd: The existence of generics means that there are lots of types that are in fact sealed, but which the code using them will not statically know to be sealed.  After I write the earlier question, though, I figured out the reason GetType works as it does: each declared value type actually represents two types with the CLR: an unboxed value type, and boxed heap type.  The former type is only used for describing storage locations; the latter for object instances.  Things stored in value-type storage locations are just combinations of bits, and are outside the type system.

Answer (score 4):

You can't [box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) a nullable.

You could do something like this:

```
public static Type GetCompilerType<T>(this T @object)
{
  return typeof (T);
}

int? x = 5;
Console.WriteLine(x.GetCompilerType());
// prints:
// System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]
```

Comment: Identifier expected; 'object' is a keyword

Comment: @slaks, thanks... forgot to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Because the type of "5" is int.

If you want to detect if a type is nullable, and the underlying type, use something like this:

```
public static Type GetActualType(Type type, out bool isNullable)
{
    Type ult = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
    if (ult != null)
    {
        isNullable = true;
        return ult;
     }
     isNullable = false;
     return type;
}
```

Comment: That is not correct, SLaks.  Look at the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype.aspx which says: "Return Value
Type: System.Type
The type argument of the nullableType parameter, if the nullableType parameter is a closed generic nullable type; otherwise, null."

Comment: You're right; I misremembered.  However, this doesn't answer the question.  `x` **is** an `int?`.

Comment: Yes, but it's in an `int?` variable.  The reason you're seeing `int` is that `int?` gets boxed to `int`.

Comment: Slaks, I think we're saying the same thing.  You're just saying it a bit more completely, but also with unnecessary aggression as your original comment about Nullable.GetUnderlyingType.