# Why does ((int?) 1).GetType() return typeof(int)?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nullable type is not a nullable type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785358/nullable-type-is-not-a-nullable-type)
>   [Why GetType returns System.Int32 instead of Nullable<Int32>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931783/why-gettype-returns-system-int32-instead-of-nullableint32)

I expected `((int?) 1).GetType()` to return `typeof(int?)`, but it turns out that it returns `typeof(int)`:

```
bool a = ((int?)1).GetType() == typeof(int?); // a is false
bool b = ((int?)1).GetType() == typeof(int); // b is true
```

Still, code such as `((int?) 1).HasValue` compiles and runs just fine.

Why does casting an `int` to `int?` return an `int`?

Note that this also holds true if I replace the constant (`1`) with some `int`-variable.