# How to get a Nullable<T> instance's type

Tags: c#, types, nullable

If I do this:

```
Type type = typeof(Nullable<int>);
```

The `type` variable holds the correct `Nullable'1` type.

However, If I try to do this:

```
Nullable<int> n = 2;
Type type = n.GetType();
```

`type` ends up holding `System.Int32` which is the underlying type, but not what I am expecting.

How can I get the type of a `Nullable<>` instance?

Keep in mind that I don't know the underlying type of the nullable instance, so I cannot call `typeof`.

Comment: @NirajDoshi I don't see how this is a duplicate. I'm not asking why am I not getting the correct type, but rather how can I get the correct one.

Comment: Check the other duplicate, it contains an explanation *and* a solution which is similar to the answer posted below.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6931816/1228 is the answer in the dupe that tells you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not elegant, but you can wrap it in a generic function:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int? i = 2;
    Console.WriteLine( type(i) );
}

public static Type type<T>( T x ) { return typeof(T); }
```