# C# variable type name

Tags: c#

Is there a way to get `o1` variable type during runtime instead of the instance type it is referencing?

`o1.GetVariableType` or something like that which returns the compile-time static type of the variable? In o1's case, `System.Object` rather than `System.Double`?

Thanks.

```
{
    double? d1 = 4.4;
    object o1 = d;
    Console.WriteLine(d1.GetType());
    Console.WriteLine(o1.GetType());
}
```

this prints out

> System.Double
>
> System.Double

Edit: Scheme posted the link that actually answered my question.

[How to get compile time type of a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906609/how-to-get-compile-time-type-of-a-variable)

Comment: Why would you need a method or operation for this?  You already know the compile time type (you have to, by definition).

Comment: as additional note you could use `typeof(object)` or `typeof(double)` to get the type you want

Comment: Can you explain what the higher level goal is? What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Purely for my edification. I want to know if it is possible. Why is this labeled as duplicate when "Type Checking: typeof, GetType, or is? " doesn't answer it?

Comment: @Scheme That's also the only way to get the `Nullable<double>` type as opposed to just being told it's a `System.Double`

Comment: @Cee My pleasure, i was trying to answer when it got dupped.

Comment: Note that you are also seeing a weirdness of Nullable here. When a not-null instance of Nullable is cast to an object, it becomes its value, with no Nullable wrapper. GetType() is a non-virtual method of Object, so GetType() on any variable will never return Nullable. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931783/why-gettype-returns-system-int32-instead-of-nullableint32